# show members of a list

Tags: java, jsp

Hi I am using following code to retrieve the values of a list but it does not show anything.
My class code is:

```
    private List MyList;
    public List getMyList() {
            System.out.println("MyList:"+MyList.get(0).toString());
            return MyList;
    }

    public void setMyList(List MyList) {
            this.MyList = MyList;
    }
```

My jsp:

```
 <c:forEach var="item" items="${MyList}">
   <div>${item}</div>
 </c:forEach>
```

Result in console : MyList:Swimming

but no result in browser !!!!

Comment: There is convention that all variables start with lower case character in Java.

Comment: are you setting list in request attribute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since jstl expressions will be evaluated by the naming convention for getters/setters, you have to use the following inside your jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${myList}">
   <div>${item}</div>
 </c:forEach>
```

`${myList}` will be evalutated to `getMyList()`.

Comment: I used it but it does not work, the source of page shows                <c:forEach var="item" items="[Swimming]">
                     <div></div>
                    </c:forEach>

Comment: maybe you forgot to import the jstl core taglib:  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

Comment: Thanks o-richie-nal it solved the problem, I do not know to tick your answer as accepted as there is no tick beside your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (if syntax is wrong please correct me):

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${myList}">
   <div>${item.toString()}</div>
 </c:forEach>
```

And Make sure your Items can be represented with the ToString() Methode. In Your case the getList Methode is called once in the Foreach loop, but its before and not incide the `<div>` section.